# How do I successfully use jquery in emberjs

Tags: jquery, ember.js, node-modules

I'm attempting to change the value of an ember 'Input Helper' whenever a separate 'Input Helper' is clicked. The array of js objects is displayed in a child component as is the two Input Helpers the user interacts with. I have the actions bubble up into the template controller and handle and changes to the data there, where I would have thought the tracked objects array would update to show the new 'Input Helper' value. That isn't the case however.

I've moved onto installing the @ember/jquery add-on with

`ember install @ember/jquery`

and importing into my project with

`import jQuery from 'jquery';`

I even enabled Ember's jquery integration, even though I'm fairly certain it has been deprecated, according to this: https://rfcs.emberjs.com/id/0705-deprecate-jquery-optional-feature/After all of this is said and done, ember throws the following error:

`TypeError: requireNode is not a function`

Here is the full error stack:

```
Navigated to http://10.0.0.69:4200/add-cards
DEBUG: ------------------------------- index.js:170
DEBUG: Ember      : 4.10.0 index.js:170
DEBUG: Ember Data : 4.9.1 index.js:170
DEBUG: ------------------------------- index.js:170
GEThttp://10.0.0.69:4200/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]



Error occurred:

- While rendering:
  -top-level
    application
      add-cards

runtime.js:4985
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: requireNode is not a function
    require wrap-require.js:12
    Ember 13
    resolveComponent opcode-compiler.js:194
    encodeOp opcode-compiler.js:2126
    pushOp opcode-compiler.js:2067
    <anonymous> opcode-compiler.js:1715
    compile opcode-compiler.js:417
    compileStatements opcode-compiler.js:2070
    maybeCompile opcode-compiler.js:2049
    compile opcode-compiler.js:2032
    <anonymous> runtime.js:2973
    evaluate runtime.js:1052
    evaluateSyscall runtime.js:4214
    evaluateInner runtime.js:4185
    evaluateOuter runtime.js:4178
    next runtime.js:5009
    _execute runtime.js:4996
    execute runtime.js:4971
    sync runtime.js:5054
    runInTrackingTransaction validator.js:138
    sync runtime.js:5054
    Ember 3
    inTransaction runtime.js:4090
    Ember 5
    invoke backburner.js:284
    flush backburner.js:197
    flush backburner.js:360
    _end backburner.js:801
    _boundAutorunEnd backburner.js:525
    promise callback*buildNext/< backburner.js:26
    flush Ember
    _scheduleAutorun backburner.js:967
    _end backburner.js:807
    _boundAutorunEnd backburner.js:525
    promise callback*buildNext/< backburner.js:26
    flush Ember
    _scheduleAutorun backburner.js:967
    _end backburner.js:807
    _boundAutorunEnd backburner.js:525
    promise callback*buildNext/< backburner.js:26
    flush Ember
    _scheduleAutorun backburner.js:967
    _end backburner.js:807
    _boundAutorunEnd backburner.js:525
    promise callback*buildNext/< backburner.js:26
    flush Ember
    _scheduleAutorun backburner.js:967
    _end backburner.js:807
    _boundAutorunEnd backburner.js:525
    promise callback*buildNext/< backburner.js:26
    flush Ember
    _scheduleAutorun backburner.js:967
    _ensureInstance backburner.js:958
    schedule backburner.js:651
    <anonymous> Ember
    fulfill rsvp.js:383
    resolve$1 rsvp.js:363
    initializePromise rsvp.js:465
    Ember 2
    initializePromise rsvp.js:460
    Promise rsvp.js:916
    Ember 7
    invokeCallback rsvp.js:435
    then rsvp.js:492
    <anonymous> Ember
    invoke backburner.js:282
    flush backburner.js:197
    flush backburner.js:360
    _end backburner.js:801
    end backburner.js:592
    _run backburner.js:845
    run backburner.js:627
    Ember 7
wrap-require.js:12
```

I wasn't able to identify what the issue was or why this would occur. There isn't much that I found relating to this specific error.

Comment: do you have an open source reproduction? I'd love to poke around

Comment: Not that this really helps but you probably shouldn't use jQuery. Ember should have all the functionality you need you want to change the value of something you could just use tracked properties and assign values to them.

Comment: After a lot of trial, error and new ideas I came to the same conclusion. I've been able to accomplish what I was attempting by using 

document.querySelector("#html_id_here").value;

Comment: Have you considered using a TrackedMap from the `tracked-built-ins` addon instead of a tracked object? I think this would be better than trying to manipulate the DOM yourself.

Answer (score 2):

While I strongly recommend never using jQuery in modern applications, in Ember 4.0 and above the correct way to use jQuery is:

`npm install --save-dev jquery`

and

`import $ from 'jquery';` in any file that uses it.

Do not use the `@ember/jquery` addon. It only works in Ember 3.x.

(Notice how this is just like any other modern framework!)